# お＋Vます＋ください vs お＋Vます＋になってください

Tags: nuances, honorifics, comparison

I was wondering if there is a slight nuance difference between these 2 honorific patterns. 
I 'll give an examle with 座る.

1)お座りください。
2) お座りになってください。(or as it is commonly encountered: お掛けになってください。)

To my understanding the 2nd example is just a tad more honorific since it uses になる making it a bit more "extra"

There are even everyday examples that use both in the same sentence structure:
例）こちらに**お掛けになって**、少々**お待ちください**。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the 2nd example 「おすわりになってください（おかけになってください）」 is slightly more polite since 「お〜になってください」is a request expression.

「お〜になってください」is very polite (almost too polite for daily life) so 「お〜ください」is more commonly used in every day life situation. For example,"Please wait here."

- a) こちらで　お待ちになってください。
- b) こちらで　お待ちください。

b) is more likely used.

「こちらにお掛けになって、少々お待ちください。」is a definitely everyday life sentence example. Because 「お〜になってください」has been used at the first part (お掛けになって), so you wouldn't say お掛けになって、少々お待ちになってください。